# Potter Cryptic Clues

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

Today is July 31st, which, according to JK Rowling, is apparently Harry Potter's birthday.  So, let's celebrate with some Harry Potter themed cryptic clues!
  The final answer is a good bit of trivia:

1. Order mobile phone number nine (7)
2. Ghost war damaged the school (8)
3. Ron sat up... oddly familiar (8)
4. School teacher lift off: The start of war with headless Nick (8)
5. Screen writer exchanged a jogging machine? (8)
6. Follower cut deal, ending drama (5-5)
7. Weasley's dearest minion, missing in the east, follows any girl (8)
8. Line up six, oh mad moon's master? (11)
9. A boorish dolt is with us! (6)
10. The messenger mercury takes flying wide to heart (6)

Final Answer:
   **1-2-3-4-6-10-4-4-1-2**

Comment: Good work everyone, this was a real team effort! :)

Comment: Great team solve! Thanks for playing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's put an answer together:

1. From @F1Krazy

   > **P**HOENIX (Order: PHOEN (anagram of "phone") + IX (Roman numerals for nine))
2. From @F1Krazy

   > H**O**GWARTS (School: anagram of "ghost war")
3. From @F1Krazy

   > PA**T**RONUS (Familiar: anagram of "RON SAT UP")
4. From Me

   > FLI**T**WICK (Schoolteacher, mixed up "LIFT" + start of "WAR" + headless "NICK")
5. From @psmears

   > PENSI**E**VE ((Memory)-Jogging Machine, screen = "SIEVE" & writer = "PEN", exchanged)
6. From @F1Krazy & my wordplay

   > DEATH EATE**R** (Follower, cut ending of "DEAL" = "DEA" + drama "THEATER")
7. From @Matt

   > HER**M**IONE (Weasley's dearest, from "MINION" - "IN" = "MION", east = "E", and following any girl "HER" -> "HER" + "MION" + "E"
8. From @Yve

   > XEN**O**PHILIUS (Moon's (Luna's) master), anagram of "LINE UP SIX OH")
9. From @Yve

   > **R**UBEUS (Boorish dolt = "RUBE" + "US")
10. From Me

    > H**E**DWIG (Messenger, Mercury "Hg", flying "WIDE" (rearranges to "EDWI") to the heart of "HG" -> "H" + "EDWI" + "G")

If we take

> The nth letter of each answer according to your sequence, we have a final answer of **POTTERMORE**! (Thanks to @F1Krazy and @Matt and @Yve and @psmears for additional letters!)

Comment: Correct on everything so far.  You almost have enough to put it all together!

Comment: I think I've got the missing 5 (see my answer :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not much good at cryptic clues, but here's a start:

1.

> PHOENIX (Order: PHOEN (anagram of "phone") + IX (Roman numerals for nine))

2.

> HOGWARTS (The school: anagram ("damaged") of "Ghost war")

3.

> PATRONUS (Familiar: anagram ("oddly") of "Ron sat up")

6.

> Suspect it's DEATH EATER (Follower), but can't figure out how it fits the clue

Comment: Right on all of them, even #6!  @El-Guest's answer has the wordplay

Answer (score 7):

I'll toss this in for 7

> HERMIONE = any girl (HER)- which everything else follows-, dearest minion, missing in (MION), the east (E)

Comment: Correct!  (the full def is 'Weasley's dearest' just to clarify)

Answer (score 6):

I got two more:
8.

> XENOPHILIUS ("mad" referring to an anagram of "line up six oh," "moon's master" meaning Luna's father)

  9.

> RUBEUS (RUBE is "a boorish dolt" + US, "!" makes it a [mean] description of Hagrid!)

Comment: Both are correct! Great solves @Yve,  And welcome to the Puzzling Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thank you @TwoBitOperation ! I was browsing Math Stack Exchange and of course got distracted when I saw "cryptic" in the sidebar!

Answer (score 5):

And for 5:

> Pensieve - to screen something is to sieve it (as in silk screen etc); a pen is a writer; exchanged turns "sieve pen" into "pen sieve", and the Pensieve is (kind of) a machine for jogging one's memory.

Comment: Perfect!! I think you've got it!!

Comment: Exactly right. In my opinion this was the toughest clue, great job!